# How to detect last call to server in GWT?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, gwt, gmail

I want to detect last asynchronous call to server, because i want to display loading box before all javascript code download and display successfully.

Like gmail- gmail display loading box after sign in before all javascript code download and display properly

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a unified RPC caller that handle retries on errors and display your loading box.